# How to activate pistons with a command block?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I'm working on a hunger game map on pc minevraft windows 10 and I cant build over the water with Redstone so I want to be able to activate and deactivate the pistons manually using a command block but I can't figure out the command if someone can please help me out.

Comment: Which game are you playing, MCJava, MCBE, MCCE, …? Also, what do you mean with "I cant build over the water with Redstone"? And what's wrong with just setting a redstone block?

Comment: on pc windows 10 edition, I want to be able to activate and deactivate the pistons from a distance without redstone.

Comment: Then you'll need to set an extended piston and a piston head. But I have no idea how to do that in MCBE.

Comment: @ArthurAkopyan, can you add that to the question, so it's clearer what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Just `/setblock` the block in-front/behind/below/left/right (basically any side but "above", or whichever way your Piston is facing) to be a Redstone Block.